# jQuery вывести значения из массива в блоки с одинаковым классом

Tags: jquery, массивы

Получаю содержимое label отмеченного input type=radio, и добавляю в массив. Затем нужно каждый элемент массива вывести в  html  в блоки к классом "concretisize_uslug".

```
$("#diametrDop").change(function(){ 
    var arr_sel_uslug=[];
    $(".usltype").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            var cncr = $(this).closest('li').find('label').text();
            arr_sel_uslug.push(cncr);           
            }
        });
    $.each(arr_sel_uslug, function (index, value) {             
        var cncruslug=value;
        $(".concretisize_uslug").each(function(){
            $(this).html(cncruslug);                
        });                     
    }); 
});
```

Это блок выводит в каждый элемент с классом .concretisize_uslug последний элемент массива.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём заключается?))) Ещё неплохо добавить html разметку. и пояснить в чём проблема сейчас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(arr_sel_uslug, function (index, value) {             
  var cncruslug = value;
  $(".concretisize_uslug").each(function(){
    $(this).html(cncruslug);                
  });                     
});
```

Здесь каждый элемент массива (он же, value) на каждой итерации добавляется во все блоки `$(".concretisize_uslug")`, переписывая предыдущие значения. По завершению перебора остается только последнее значение. Исправленный вариант:

```
$(".concretisize_uslug").each(function(index) {
  $(this).html( arr_sel_uslug[index] );
  // если тут не HTML-строка, заменить .html() на .text()
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло